# Why ng(angular-cli) is not recognized as internal or external command?

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I tried everything.I set the path variable.But nothing worked.Then i tried using ng command by running command line in administrator mode.And it worked.But it doesn't work untill i run it as administrator.Can anyone help me overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't not use administrator privileges for npm installs, it may cause to a lot of problems. use this link as [official guide](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)